# Making a list with np.array itself

Tags: arrays, numpy

I was watching a tutorial where he plotted an array on the x axis and wasn't able to understand,
array was like-  `np.array([0,100])`
How does this work? does this generate values from 0 to 100 or just an array with two values 0 and 100?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will create an create an array with 2 elements 0 and 100 and returns the created array.

The type is :<class 'numpy.ndarray'>